# How to grab ID of element which ID has been dynamically given?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I’m trying to make a simple show when checkbox is checked kind of section but am unable to get a hold of the element because the IDs of the element are assigned dynamically by PHP.

The element will be inside a foreach loop so there will be multiple instances of it with dynamically given IDs.

example:

```
//Laravel blade template
<element id="attrb{{ $elem->id }}> "></element>

//Javascript
if ($("#attrb*ID").is(":checked")) {
    $("#attrbs-container").show();
} else {
    $("#attrbs-container").hide();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using `jQuery` so maybe you want to look into using their `.on()` function for binding events on dynamic elements. [**jQuery .on() Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jquery

```js
$('input[id^="attrb"]').change(function(e){
     
    if($(this).is(':checked'))  console.log($(this).prop('id'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" id="attrb1" value="1" />
```

Run, and check the box.  You can replace `console.log` with your `.show` or whatever.

The selector `input[id^="attrb"]` means an `input` with an `id` that `^=` starts with `attrb`.  You could also use `input[type="checkbox"]` if these are the only checkboxes you have, but it's less specific.

**Change vs Click**

`change` fires when the data (state) of the element changes. `click` will trigger anytime you click.  In this case it probably doesn't matter too much which you use.  A better example of `change` vs `click` is using radio buttons, and clicking an already checked radio.  Checkboxes un-click when checked, radio buttons not so much.  I'm just in a habit of using `change` over `click` for state changes.

```js
$('input[id^="attrb"]').click(function(e){
     
    if($(this).is(':checked'))  console.log($(this).prop('id'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" id="attrb1" value="1" />
```

Run and click the radio 2x.  It fires 2 times.

```js
$('input[id^="attrb"]').change(function(e){
     
    if($(this).is(':checked'))  console.log($(this).prop('id'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" id="attrb1" value="1" />
```

Do the same thing here, but with change.  That's the difference.

**DYNAMIC vs Dynamic**

What I mean here is `DYNAMIC` is something that changes at run time on the client, `Dynamic` is static HTML where the ID changes on the server side only.  For DYNAMIC you want to use `on` like this

```
 $(someparent).on('change', 'input[id^="attrb"]', function(e){ ... });
```

Where `someparent` is a static element that doesn't change at runtime.  This will use event delegation and "bubbling" to find the content that was changed on the client side.

I don't think you meant DYNAMIC but I included it just in case.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you could create a function with a callback if you're assigning the id with javascript (after an ajax request)

```
function addID(add, callback)
```

Then use the funciton:

```
addId(function(){
    //dynamically add ID
}, function(){
    // callback function
    if ($(“#attrb*ID”).is(":checked")) {
        $(“#attrbs-container").show();
    } else {
        $(“#attrbs-container").hide();
    }
})
```